# Add shadow to frame of UITextView add also shadow to text

Tags: ios, uitextview, dropshadow, quartz-core

I have a UITextView where I add some drop shadow to the frame, but when I write, the text got also the same shadow. How to avoid this problem?

My code :

```
commentary = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 435, 230, 120)];
commentary.font = STANDARDFONT;
commentary.backgroundColor = BACKGROUND;
commentary.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
commentary.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2, 2);
commentary.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
commentary.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0;
commentary.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
commentary.layer.borderWidth = 1.5;
commentary.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
commentary.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
commentary.clipsToBounds = NO;
[self addSubview:commentary];
```

BACKGROUND and STANDARDFONT is `[UICOLOR clearColor].CGColor`and `[UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRomanPSMT" size:16];`

Comment: I haven't found a solution, so I remove the dropshadow instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the layer background color also: `commentary.layer.backgroundColor = BACKGROUND.CGColor`

Comment: Sorry, my fault. The BACKGROUND color is clear, not black. But if I set the `commentary.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];`the whole uitextview turns black. 

What I want is that the text inside the box stay without shadow.